# django named url not picking variables

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following url pattern -

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<var>[\w]+)/(?P<var_slug>[\w-])/$', 'player_detail', name='player_detail'),
```

In my view, I have the following -

```
model_dict = {"player":PlayerProfile, "event":PlayerEvent, "need":PlayerNeed}
def player_list(request, var=None, var_slug=None):
    '''
    displays the list of vars
    '''
    objs = model_dict.get(var).objects.filter(slug=var_slug).order_by('-creation_time')[:20]
    template_name = "list_"+str(var)+"s.html"
    return render(request, template_name, {"objs":objs})
```

In my templates I finally do the following -

```
<a href="{% url 'player_detail' var='baseball' slug='obj.slug'  %}">details of Player</a>
```

The error I get is following -

```
Reverse for 'player_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'var': u'baseball', u'slug': u'obj.slug'}' not found.
```

What am I missing?

also, is it a good way to pick models dynamically depending on the variable in the parameter, and generating a template name on the fly?

Answer (score 3):

`slug='obj.slug'` should be `slug=obj.slug`

Your regex doesn't match a `.`

Also you probably want`[\w-]+` just like your other regex.. one or more [\w or -]